# In postgres how to get sum (or rollup) of a field within certain time range from a event log type table (which has timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which has data like this

```
event_type event_cnt timestamp
abc         2          2016-1-1 20:08:01
abc         3          2016-1-1 20:10:01
xyz        10          2016-1-1 20:10:01
abc         1          2016-1-1 20:15:01
xyz         5          2016-1-1 20:30:01
xyz         5          2016-1-1 20:31:01
```

I want a result which is a sum (cluster) of event_cnt within 2 minutes.

```
event_type  event_cnt_within_2_min
abc   5 (which is 2+3 in two minutes)
xyz   10 
abc   1
xyz   10 (which is 5+5 in two minutes)
```

I think there might be a way to use the analytical function to solve this, but I cannot get to working solution yet.

Comment: What if you have an event every minute during 10 minutes? Should that become one record, or how will you split those records into groups?

Comment: Yes, that will be one record and sum of all. As long as the records are within in 2 minutes apart, they will be summed up. I added `event_type` in my example to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use lead function to check if the next event inserted in the next 2 min.

```
    select event_type,
           sum(case when datediff(minute,timestamp,lead_timestamp)<=2 then lead_event_cunt else 0 end) + 
           sum(event_cnt) as event_cunt_within_2_min
    from(       
    select event_type,event_cnt,timestamp,
           lead (timestamp,1) over (partition by event_type order by timestamp) as lead_timestamp,
           lead (event_cunt,1) over (partition by event_type order by timestamp) as lead_event_cunt,
    from mytable)
    group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks! works great with minor correction: it should be  `LEAD(timestamp,1)`

Comment: your right , i didn't check the script before , i will update that